# Can I use an instance variable as the key for an associative array?

Tags: php

The array is an instance variable of the same object. I want to keep track about what instance variable has changed it's value, so it seems to be a simple solution to pass the instance variable itself as an key to an associative array.

Is this perfectly fine with PHP or does this have some bad side effects?

Comment: You have 2 Options: `A) Explain what you are doing more indepth`, or `B) Give us a Code Example`. Either will do, but otherwise I just don't understand your question enough to provide an answer.

Comment: And yes, I realize that the answer is `keys must be scalar`, but if you want another solution to the problem you are trying to fix with a object key, you need to give us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; the key must be a scalar. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Depending on the scenario, one solution might be to associate an index with the objects in question, and then use this index for the array, or you could have for each value an object/array containing the object in question, and whatever information you want to associate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Keys of arrays can only be strings or integers.